# Submit dynamic table inputs

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to store a table data in my website. The table has `n` row and every row has `m` column (It is a dynamic table). Every cell has an input. So we have `n * m` inputs.

How can I store data in `JSON` format?

```
Example:
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| {row-1,column-1} | {row-1,column-2} | {row-1,column-3} |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| {row-2,column-1} | {row-2,column-2} | {row-2,column-3} |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| {row-3,column-1} | {row-3,column-2} | {row-3,column-3} |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| {row-4,column-1} | {row-4,column-2} | {row-4,column-3} |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Stored data :

```
JSON Object:
[
  [ {"row-1,column-1"},{"row-1,column-2"},{"row-1,column-3"} ], // row 1
  [ {"row-2,column-1"},{"row-2,column-2"},{"row-2,column-3"} ], // row 2
  [ {"row-3,column-1"},{"row-3,column-2"},{"row-3,column-3"} ], // row 3
  [ {"row-4,column-1"},{"row-4,column-2"},{"row-4,column-3"} ]  // row 4
]
```

Is there any `jQuery` solution or `plugin` ?

Comment: Why does it have to be JSON? If you use array-style input names, the server will create an array from the parameters.

Comment: @user191183 It it your purpose?

Comment: @user191183 If my answer is helpful, please mark it to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

First get every `tr` using `each` and in it, get event `td` of row using another `each()`. Then add text of every `td` to object. At end convert object to json.

```js
var obj = [];
$("table tr").each(function(index){
    obj[index] = [];
    $(this).find("td").each(function(index2){
        obj[index][index2] = [$(this).text()];
    });
});
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);
```

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row1-Column1</td>
        <td>Row1-Column2</td>
        <td>Row1-Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row2-Column1</td>
        <td>Row2-Column2</td>
        <td>Row2-Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row3-Column1</td>
        <td>Row3-Column2</td>
        <td>Row3-Column3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```